# How to compare multiple values of dictionary and print the specific one

Tags: python, dictionary, count, compare, max

> One of the important tasks in computational biology is to find short
> repeating patterns from DNA sequences. These patterns help the
> biologists to analyze the functionality of different parts in a living
> being. As a computer science student, you are asked to write a program
> that will find all the patterns of a given length from a DNA sequence
> and their number of presence in that sequence. This information will
> help to find the dominant pattern of a given length in the sequence.
> You will also find the dominant pattern. Dominant pattern is the
> sequence which has maximum occurrence. If there are multiple dominant
> pattern the program will print “No Dominant Pattern found.”
>
> Sample Input:  ATTCGATCG 3  Sample Output:  ATT 1 TTC 1 TCG 2 CGA 1
> GAT 1 ATC 1  Dominant Pattern: TCG
>
> Sample Input:  ATTCGATCGATC 4  Sample Output:  ATTC 1 TTCG 1 TCGA 2
> CGAT 2 GATC 2 ATCG 1  No Dominant Pattern found.

This is the question I am trying to solve I have covered almost the whole thing however I am struggling with the last bit of code which printing the *dominating string and no dominating string.*

```
dna = input()
new = []
n =0
for n in range(len(dna)-2):
    new.append(dna[n:n+3])
    n = n + 1

count = {}
for element in new:
    if element in count:
        count[element] += 1
    else:
        count[element] = 1
for keys, value in count.items():
    print("{} {}".format(keys, value))

max_value = 0
for key, value in count.items():
    if int(value) > max_value:
        if value == max_value:
            pass
        else:
            max_value = value

print(max_value)

def max_key(val):
    for key, value in count.items():
        if val == value:
            return key
print(max_key(max_value))
```

And where and how can I shorten the code

**I am totally new**

Answer (score 0):

```
dna = input()
new = [] 
n =0
for n in range(len(dna)-2):
    new.append(dna[n:n+3])
    n = n + 1

count = {}
Dominant_Pattern={}
maxcount=0
for element in new:
    if element in count:
        count[element] += 1
    else:
        count[element] = 1
    
    if count[element]>maxcount:
        maxcount= count[element]
        Dominant_Pattern=element +" "+str(maxcount)

 
# print(list(count.keys()) [list(count.values()).index(maxcount)])
print(Dominant_Pattern)
```

if you want all the Dominant_Patternyou can uncomment this
`print(list(count.keys()) [list(count.values()).index(maxcount)])`